# Prevent Visual Studio from deleting output files from referenced projects

Tags: visual-studio, configuration

I've got a Class Library project and a Console project.  Inside the Class Library project there's a folder called "ConfigSettings" containing a configuration file that's referenced by the App.config file.  Its "Copy to Output Directory" is set to "Copy Always".

The Console project references this Class Library project.  When the console project is built, the ConfigSettings folder is created in the correct place along with the external config file.  However, every time I Debug the Console project, the external config file is deleted.  The ConfigSettings folder however is left untouched.  If I mark the file as read-only it is not deleted, and warning appears in Visual Studio's Error List:

```
Warning     Unable to delete file "C:\<path>\<app>\bin\Debug\ConfigSettings\settings.config". Access to the path 'C:\<path>\<app>\bin\Debug\ConfigSettings\settings.config' is denied.
```

Is there a setting I can change that will prevent VS from removing this file when I Debug the project?  I am using Visual Studio 2015.

Comment: I had a similar issue, but I wasn't able to recreate your issue (in VS2015). What version are you using?

Comment: I've since moved to Visual Studio 2017 and I no longer experience this issue.  I'll update this submission if it happens again.

Comment: I am using VS2017 and it is removing "ini" and "json" files from my output as well. Do you know how to prevent this?

Answer (score 0):

This might not be the best solution possible, but I found [here](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/3c2eacd0-79cc-4842-82e7-01d27d1a7b21/vs2008-delete-projects-output-files-with-no-reason-and-log?forum=vseditor), if you do a "Clean solution" just before executing your solution, the files will remain.